# Scanning for string from a file

Tags: c, string, file

For example I have a file with the following data:

```
22 John Sm1th 3.14
```

I want to store `22` to an `int`, `John Sm1th` to a string, `3.14` to a `float`.

```
int main()
{
    int n;
    char str[51];
    float f;

    FILE *fp;
    fp=fopen("aaa.txt");

    fscanf(fp, "%d", &n);
    fflush(stdin);
    fgets(str, ***, fp);
    fflush(stdin);
    fscanf(fp, "%d", &f);

    fclose(fp);
    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

In the f`gets()` call, how will I know what number to put in *** ? I can't really use `strlen()` or `sizeof()` to get the size since the string hasn't been read yet.

Comment: By the way, if you want to use `scanf` to read into a `float` variable, you should use the `"%f"` format specifier.

Answer (score 0):

```
fgets(str, sizeof(str), fp);
```

`fgets` reads at most one less than the number of characters specified by the second parameter, so you provide it with the size of the buffer, not the size of the string you read eventually.

For instance, you read a line of size 20, then `fgets` read 20 characters and encounters the new line, it stops and stores the line in the buffer.   If you read a line of size 60, then `fgets` read up to 50 (`sizeof(str) - 1`), and stores the data in the buffer.

---

BTW, `fflush(stdin);` is undefined behavior in standard C, but some implementations may support it.

Comment: `fflush(stdin)` is defined if the platform is Windows; it is undefined on (most) other platforms.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Yeah, I wasn't clear on that, fixed. As I recall, it's also defined in Linux. [man fflush](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fflush)

Comment: Hmmm...interesting. Linux [`fflush()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fflush) does define it (_For input streams, fflush() discards any buffered data that has been fetched from the underlying file, but has not been consumed by the application_).  It's a sensible, even useful definition (and matches what Microsoft defines).

Answer (score 0):

As you have a digit in the string you want to read, you can't really use the set format of `scanf`, and you can't use `fgets` as you don't know beforehand how long the interior string is.

The best bet is probably to read the whole line, then tokenize (with e.g. [`strtok`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtok)) on spaces. Get the first and last token, and convert to numbers, while you get all middle tokens and concatenate them into a single string.